# show highest values in duplicate data mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table

```
---------------------------------------------
id | name   | code   |  grade 
---------------------------------------------
1  | john   | ab12   | C
2  | john   | ab12   | D
3  | tom    | bb11   | B
4  | tom    | bb12   | A
5  | john   | ab12   | A
6  | alice  | ab12   | C 
7  | alice  | ab12   | D
8  | john   | bb11   | D
9  | john   | bb11   | C
---------------------------------------------
```

I want show data with highest value with name john

```
---------------------------------------------
id | name   | code   |  grade 
---------------------------------------------
1  | john   | ab12   | A
2  | john   | bb11   | C
---------------------------------------------
```

I try this code from the answer, but not working. error, no result
What when wrong

```
$result=mysql_query("select code max(grade) as grade
from grade
where name = 'john'
group by code");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
   echo"<table border='1'>";
echo"<tr><td height='23'>$row[name]</td>";
echo"<td height='23'>$row[code]</td>";
echo"<td height='23'>$row[grade]</td></tr>";
echo"</table>";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of id in your result set !!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all names do

```
select name, code max(grade) as grade
from your_table
group by name, code
```

and only for `John`

```
select code, max(grade) as grade
from your_table
where name = 'John'
group by code
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource. I write the code at top. its still error

Comment: I forgot a comma in the second query. Try again please.

Answer (score 0):

answered

```
$result=mysql_query("select name,code, min(grade) as grade
from grade
where name='john'
group by code");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
    echo"<table border='1'>";
  echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td height='23'>$row[name]</td>";
            echo"<td height='23'>$row[code]</td>";
            echo"<td height='23'>$row[grade]</td>";
              echo"</tr>";
echo"</table>";

}
```